# Report on data for a particular month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a data sheet in Excel that gets populated with generic information first (Data, Project code etc.) and then along columns there are questions asked in a survey (40 in total). There are predefined answers (A, B, C etc.)
So a Row would look a little something like this:

```
Date / Contract# / Sector      / Q1 / Q2 / Q3.......... Q40
12/05  010632      Department    A    B   N/A.......... Not Checked
20/07  022365      Department    N/A  C   Not Checked.. Not Checked
01/10  032501      Department    A    A   N/A.......... Not Checked
```

What I would like to report on is for a particular month, give me the questions with the most "A" answers showing the following (for instance).

What would be the best way to do this?

I cannot seem to get it to work in PivotTables and VLOOKUPs, but not sure they are best suited for this extraction of data.

Comment: if you put a helper column with the formula `=Month(A1)` you can get the month to report on via PivotTable. Otherwise, why is the PivotTable not working?

Answer (score 0):

I would properly go for the next free column as a countif formula reaching over the question answers, so countif(D2:AD2,"A")  I Say AD2 But just drag until questions have all been selected on that row....Then in the next column either a month formula as suggested or a TEXT(A2,"MMMMMM") Will show the month....Then Standard pivot.

Hope this helps
Thanks
Chris